# How to create user in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

In Parse, to make a new user, I used:

```
var user = PFUser()
user.username = "myUsername"
user.password = "myPassword"
user.email = "email@example.com"
```

What's the code used in CloudKit to create a new user and use it for login?

Comment: You can fetch record of the current user using [CKContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID:completionHandler:)

Comment: How can i use it to make a sign up app? Which will add a new user with Username, Email Id & Password?

Comment: I don't think you can generate your own signup sequence. A user should be signed up to Apple Cloud for you to use Cloudkit User features.

Comment: Okk. What do you think, Parse is better or CloudKit?

Comment: There is nothing to think. Parse has shutdown its services.

Comment: Yeah! So, You use which alternative?

Comment: The Apple Cloud Kit Quick Start Guide has a good sample to prompt a user to enter login credentials from iCloud: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently. I had to create a `CKRecord` for each user that contained the user's username and password. I added their username to `NSUserDefaults` to make it easy to retrieve.

Here is the code for signing up:

```
//Check if users exist
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "MyUsers", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
            pubDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: { (records, error) in

                //error code 11 is no objects found
                if error == nil || error?.code == 11 {

                    var usernameExists = false

                    for record in records! {

                        if record.objectForKey("username") as? String == self.usernameField.text {
                            //other user with the same username exists - don't allow user to create account
                            usernameExists = true

                        }

                    }

                    if usernameExists == true {

                        //displayErrorAlert is a function in which I display an error alert to the user
                        displayErrorAlert("Username \(self.usernameField.text!) is taken. Please choose another one.", vc: self)

                    } else {
                        //user can sign up
                        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "MyUsers")
                        record.setObject(self.usernameField.text!, forKey: "username")
                        record.setObject(self.passwordField.text!, forKey: "password")

                        pubDB.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: { (record, error) in

                            if error == nil {

                                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {

                                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.usernameField.text!, forKey: "username")
                                    username = self.usernameField.text!
                                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("account", sender: self)

                                }

                            } else {

                                print(error)

                            }

                        })

                    }

                } else {

                    print(error)

                }

            })
```

Here is the code for logging in:

```
//query users to find current user
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "MyUsers", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
            pubDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: { (records, error) in

                //we do not need to check for error code 11 because a user should exist
                if error == nil {

                    var userExists = false

                    for record in records! {

                        if record.objectForKey("username") as? String == self.usernameField.text {

                            if record.objectForKey("password") as? String == self.passwordField.text {

                                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {

                                    userExists = true
                                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.usernameField.text!, forKey: "username")
                                    username = self.usernameField.text!
                                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("account", sender: self)

                                }

                            } else {

                                //user with the username exists, but the password does not match
                                displayErrorAlert("Your password is incorrect", vc: self)

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    if userExists == false {

                        //user with that username does not exist
                        displayErrorAlert("Your username is incorrect", vc: self)

                    }


                } else {

                    print(error)

                }

            })

        }
```

When the view **appears**, I call this code to check for a current user:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("username") != nil {
    username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("username") as! String
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("account", sender: self)
}
```

The `variable username` is a global variable for all classes. If you do not prefer to user global variables, you should change it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks, can u provide the whole code?

Comment: Ok. Done. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Thank you. That was what i want. :)

Comment: DOWNVOTED - This is a security risk. Passwords are world-readable, and this is a terrible approach.  If you have the ability to write to CloudKit, then you already have a userID and authentication via FetchUserRecordID

Comment: Yes but that is the user's iCloud account password. This is a temporary solution; you could encrypt the password if you would like.